# is it true that parallelogram inscribed in ellipse is rectangle

Tags: geometry

I only managed to prove that parallelogram inscribed in a circle is a rectangle.

Is it possible to prove that parallelogram inscribed in ellipse is rectangle? Maybe there are counterexamples?

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: The north,south,east and west "poles" of an ellipse form a parallelogram (in fact rhombus) which is not a rectangle if the ellipse is not a circle.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thanks to your example, I figured it out

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity how do you define a parallelogram?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity How do you inscribe a non-square rhombus into a circle?

Comment: You don't, but I also said the statement holds in that case, i.e. the figure is a rectangle (more specifically a square). But I did mix up trapeziums, parallelograms and rhombi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a rectangle inscribed into a circle. For simplicity imagine it to be aligned with coordinate axes. Apply an affine transformation to it, more specifically a shearing transformation. That will turn the right angles into something else, while at the same time preserving parallelism. It will also map conics to conics, and your original circle becomes an ellipse. So there you have it: a non-rectangular parallelogram inscribed into an ellipse.

[image: circle with inscribed rectangle] [image: ellipse with inscribed parallelogram]